# Zend Form can't validate float number

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-validate

I have this form element:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'prezzo', array(
        'label' => 'Prezzo (*)',
        'filter' => '',
        'description' => 'Il prezzo non è comprensivo di sconto, ma se previsto verrà calcolato',
        'required' => true,
        'validators' => array('Float'),
        'placeholder' => 'Prezzo Pneumatico',
        'class' => 'form-control'
    ));
```

if i put in input a number like this `24.50` I get error on validation while if i put a number like this `24,50` I don't get any error.

I think the problem is with `Zend_Locale` in my `Bootstrap.php` where i set this value:

```
protected function _initLocale() {
    $locale = new Zend_Locale ( 'it' );
    Zend_Registry::set ( 'locale', $locale );
}
```

Probably one soluction is to filter the input and replace `'.'` with `','`.
Can you help me?

Comment: By using javascript, when submit event starts, transform your float to a string, replace the dots by commas then convert it back to float (if the cast is not made automatically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want validate in *en locale* e.g. *24.50* set [locale option](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.float) to your validator.

```
$this->addElement('text', 'prezzo', array(
    'label' => 'Prezzo (*)',
    'filter' => '',
    'description' => 'Il prezzo non è comprensivo di sconto, ma se previsto verrà calcolato',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => array(array('Float', true, array('locale' => 'en'))),
    'placeholder' => 'Prezzo Pneumatico',
    'class' => 'form-control'
));
```

Comment: in this way i get this error: `Invalid validator passed to addValidators()`

Comment: Oh I missed validators must be in array.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('form[name=pneumatico]').find('input[name=prezzo]').keyup(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace('.', ','));
    });
    $('form[name=pneumatico]').find('input[name=sconto]').keyup(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace('.', ','));
    });
}); </script>
```

Thanks